# Creating multitarget nuget package with .nuspec

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, .net-standard, nuspec

I have specified multitargeting in my .csproj

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net472</TargetFrameworks>
```

When I am using below script, then my package has dependencies and it is expected result:

```
dotnet pack --output nupkgs $ProjectPath -c:Release
```

The problem is when I also want to use .nuspec file with some information about package:

```
dotnet pack --output nupkgs $ProjectPath -c:Release -p:NuspecFile=$NuspecFile
```

With .nuspec file the package has no dependencies and I can install it only in netstandard2.0...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>xyz</id>
    <version>1.2011.4</version>
    <title>xyz</title>
    <authors>xyz</authors>
    <projectUrl>xyz</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>xyz</description>
    <copyright>xyz</copyright>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Should I add something to this .nuspec to have a package with target dependencies? I have read about  tag, but to be honest I cannot find example how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using an SDK based projects, I'd strongly discourage using a nuspec unless your scenario cannot be satisfied because of it's complexity.

The automatic package generation with project file through `dotnet.exe pack` does much of the compatibility work for you.

If you really need to go with a nuspec, you should add dependency groups like defined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependency-groups.

Make sure you add the relevant framework.

Example

```xml
    <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.7.2">
        <dependency id="PackageA" version="1.2.3" />
    </group>
     <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
        <dependency id="PackageB" version="4.5.6" />
    </group>
```

Note that you need to add a dependency group for the specific frameworks you support.